# IIS URL Rewrite enforce trailing forward slash not working with resources that 404

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to get IIS URL Rewrite module to enforce the trailing forward slashes on my URLs in order to turn a request for **mysite.com/bla** into **mysite.com/bla/**.

I'm using the rule as shown below which is the one the IIS URL Rewrite wizard sets up for exactly this situation and everything works fine, but only if the file exists. As soon as we have a 404 situation, a forward slash is appended to the end of the request.

```
<rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
</rule>
```

Using the above rule the following happens:

- **www.mysite.com/bla** - Redirects to www.mysite.com/bla/ (just what I
  want)
- **www.mysite.com/bla/** - Stays as is (just what I
  want)
- **www.mysite.com/bla/myimg.jpg** - Stays as is provided myimg.jpg exists
- **www.mysite.com/bla/myimg.jpg** - Redirects to www.mysite.com/bla/myimg.jpg/ if myimg.jpg does not exist

Firstly, any idea why this is happening and how I can prevent it? If a resource 404s I just want it to 404, simple as that. Alternatively if a request for a directory is made with no trailing forward slash, I just want it appending.

Secondly, why do we have both the rule saying **if it's not a file** AND **if it's not a directory**? Surely we should be saying if it's not a file and if it is a directory (or am I misunderstanding something?).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To add to the confusion here, IIS has a thing called "Courtesy Redirects" where it will automatically add a trailing slash to folders as per here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/298408/iis-generates-courtesy-redirect-when-folder-without-trailing-slash-is-requested  -- So I suspect in your first three cases, this rule isn't firing and you're just seeing IIS default behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, any idea why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

It happens because in the conditions it says that if the requested path is an existing file or folder, the rule is not triggered:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

So when you request a non-existing file, the rule triggers.

> If a resource 404s I just want it to 404, simple as that.

The rewrite module tries first to redirect your path because it doesn't consider your request to ask for a file or folder, so it tries to reach a route. The route doesn't exist so you get a 404 eventually.

> Secondly, why do we have both the rule saying if it's not a file AND
>   if it's not a directory?

Because if you request `www.mysite.com/bla/myimg.jpg`, you probably want to display `bla/myimg.jpg` and not treat `bla/myimg.jpg` as a route. Same goes for the directory.